# Error AADSTS90093 when logging into Azure AD with non-admin/Microsoft Accounts

Tags: azure, office365, azure-active-directory

I've created a ASP.NET MVC web application that is configured to use the O365 Azure AD tenant of my company. I can login to the application with accounts that are Global Administrators in the Azure AD tenant, but login fails for both

- Internal users: O365 accounts that are no Global Administrators in the Azure AD tenant and
- Microsoft Accounts that are registered as Guest accounts.

The error message is:

> AADSTS90093: This operation can only be performed by an administrator.

The Azure AD application is a single-tenant one (but changing it to multi-tenant does not solve the issue).

The application manifest is unchanged. How can I solve this and enable the login for both internal and external users?

**Update**

As far as I can see, the app also does not require any permissions that require admin consent.

[image]

Comment: What permissions does your app require? Do some of them require admin permissions? Because if so, you must go through admin consent to enable consent for the rest of the users in the tenant.

Comment: @juunas: as far as I can see, the app does not require any admin-specific permissions. I've added a screenshot of the permission settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the application needed to be granted the permissions explicitely by clicking `Grant permissions` in the app registration settings:

[image: grant permissions in new Azure management portal]

After granting the permissions, users can log into the application without being Global Administrators.